# Apk only runs in debug mode. Apk started with "Run" in Eclipse stops on breakpoints

Tags: android, debugging, release

I note that this has been asked before but I haven't found an answer yet. The main tell tale of this problem is that Eclipse stops on break points when the apk has been deployed as "Run"

I've done these so far and none produce a correctly running "Run" build from Project shell -> Run As -> 1. Android Application

• Disconnecting, uninstalling and re installing the apk does not fix the problem (this is a tablet device, not an emulator.)
• Made all of the project and library projects write able using the file system 
• Brand new projects work correctly e.g. they don't stop on breakpoints in "Run" mode in the same Eclipse workspace as the problem project 
• Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug(expand) -> Launching "Launch in debug mode when workspace contains breakpoints" is set to never 
• Closed and opened Eclipse 
• Killed all of the running processes under the "Debug" tab in that perspective
• Cleaned the entire workspace both in Eclipse IDE and manually by deleting the res and gen folders of the main and library project dependencies
• Checked for the occurrence of the word "debug" in the project build files
• Clean built the project from the command line using: ant clean then ant release

Interestingly enough, when I clean build from the command line then fresh-install the new apk, if Eclipse is open the debugger will attach to the running process and stop at the first break point! If Eclipse is closed, the program will wait for the debugger with the standard "Waiting for Debugger" dialog.

So something is broken in the build process (haven't figured out what all files are getting involved yet) and/or something in .metadata and/or some depenency.

**edit** 
I've found a file at:

```
C:\Projects\Mobile\Android\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches\MyProjectName.launch
```

in the xml:

```
<launchConfiguration type="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.debug.LaunchConfigType">
```

Don't know if it's a clue, but if I delete the file Eclipse will just replace it with the same.

**edit**

*Confirmed that the project Runs correctly when built and run from another machine, so I suspect that it's my work machine's Eclipse workspace that's causing this issue. Maybe I need to throw out all of the workspace's metadata and start over.

Comment: Did you try right clicking then `Run as...-> Android application`

Comment: Have you killed adb and started it again? Sometimes it generates very strange behaviours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*

Use Intellij instead of Eclipse for Android development (far fewer IDE interface bugs) and then disregard the following altogether:

Two important rules I've found since the original post:

1) Get in the habit of waiting until Eclipse is finished build the workspace - the indicator shows up in the bottom left corner of Eclipse by default. WS build times can take minutes in a large project with multiple libs. Don't change anything until the build is complete.

2) Close all projects in the workspace and reopen them one-at-a-time starting with the project with no lib dependencies and so on. Make sure not to open a project until you can verify the the workspace has finished building what is already open. Fix any issues along the way before opening the next project.

Good luck.

Answer (score 14):

I encountered same issue. The solution is, restarting your device. Good luck.

Comment: I hate solving things this way, but it's the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You said you have breakpoints?

Try:

`Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug(expand) -> Launching`

There should be a section entitled **"Launch in debug mode when workspace contains breakpoints"**

If that is not on "Never" that would be your problem.

Comment: I got really excited there for a moment- "Never" has always been selected. Also tried changing it and back again - "Run" still stops on breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and I need 4 steps to resolve them:

1. Disconnect the device
2. Reboot the device
3. Clean and build all the projects in workspace.
4. Start the app in emulator in Run mode and check it's ok.
5. Start the app in the device in Run mode and all works ok.

Only restarting the device not works for me!

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered same problem: I could run my application only in debug mode, but it won't properly start when I press 'run' button. I've tried all solution here, but nothing works for me.

After some time I've found `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();` in the begining of my Activity. I hope this answer sometimes help someone, because this question was first in Google, when I search for help.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me sometimes - have you uninstalled the application completely from the handset and tried to reinstall?  Can you install the apk and then disconnect the handset from the machine? (obv won't work if you're using an emulator)

Comment: Disconnecting, uninstalling and re installing the apk does not fix the problem. I'm using a physical device only for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue on Samsung S4 and issue is fixed by unchecking "Wait for debugger" option under "Developer options".

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, check that you haven't got this line of code anywhere in your project:

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

It may exist in a Service for debugging purposes, once you comment it out it will work in release mode.  The problem is that this line of code waits for the debugger, and if you're not running in debug mode it will wait indefinitely